# Applying tag twice result in different css style

Tags: html, css

This `<h1>Some text <small><small>here</small></small></h1>`

results

[image]

and this `<h1>Some text <small>here</small></h1>`

results

[image]

and i want first one with small `here` word,  but without double `<small>` tags, so is there can be written any *rule to apply style twice* without creating new rule or touching existing for element?
Currently used rule for `<small>` tags is

`h1 small, .h1 small, h2 small, .h2 small, h3 small, .h3 small, h1 .small, .h1 .small, h2 .small, .h2 .small, h3 .small, .h3 .small {
    font-size: 65%;
}`
 
Note: The point of question is possibility to apply style twice without creating or touching existing style of element. 
For example lets say `<a>Foods</a> and <a class="twice">Cars</a>`
would become 
[image]

So `twice` can be used anywhere to apply double style (make font smaller twice or bigger twice, or transparensy level twice, or brightess twice, padding twice and etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the CSS ofcourse, but most probably (and definitely when browser agent styles are used) the `<small>` tag is defined as an `em` value, which is a relative value. So you basically say to the browser: `make this text 80% of 80% of the original` (or whatever the em value is).

Now, if you want to have only one small tag, and have the same result, you should apply a style to it:

**CSS**

```
small.extra-small { font-size: 0.2em; /* some extra small font size value */ }
```

**HTML**

```
<small class="extra-small">This text is tiny!</small>
```

And your question was: can I do this without changing anything? The answer is no. Because nowhere in the world you can change something without touching it (or you should be God ;)).

Answer (score 1):

Small has default `font-size` set to 75%, when you have two `small`s, result font-size is .75*75%.

Using two `small` elements isn´t the right way, use class to set extra-small font, or whatever. Not two `small` elements.

If you want to use your current HTML, just reset the `font-size` for inner `small`:

```
small small {font-size: 1em}
```